# Why not Object.ToFloat or Object.ToInt() exist?

Tags: c#

Tostring() gives the string representation of the instance?
Is it because we didn't feel the need to do any conversion from object to int/float?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Virtually any object can be converted to a string (in worst case, you can convert an object to its class name). However, you cannot say the same about int or float. How would you convert a string "asdf" into float? Or an object representing an NPC in game to an int?

By the way, noone stops you from writing your own extension method if you find a way to convert any object to an int:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static int ToInt32(this object obj)
    {
        return 42;
    }
}

// (...)

object o = new object();
int i = o.ToInt32();
```

Comment: Sir. But have another question for u!Pardon me..I came across this question?but didn't find any answer Sir. Here it is::"In OOP, all classes inherit from Object class, so y don't we write className:Object?

Comment: Argh. Please write in plain English. Noone stops you from writing `public class Test : object` or `public class Test : Object`. But because inheriting from an `object` is required, language creators decided, that writing code noting this inheritance - as being obvious - is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

If you can explain how to convert a `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` to a float - I'd love to know.

Answer (score 1):

Why should any `Object` be convertible to `Int32`? There's no need to add this method to `Object` itself. If you think that an object is convertible to `int` use the appropriate method or cast the object:

```
object obj = 1;
int num = (int) obj;
```

or

```
obj = "1";
num = System.Convert.ToInt32(obj);
```

or(if it's clearly a `String`)

```
string str = "1";
num = int.Parse(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

However, you can convert the object that could be convertible (to Int, for example) using the Convert class:

```
        object o = new object();
        o = "1234";
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because compiler does not support `.toInt()` and supports `.toString()`

You can convert number to string but not string to number. Thats why compiler does not supports it.

You can use, `int.parse` or `Convert.ToInt32` which can handle invalid numerical parts (mostly nulls)

Compiler will handle `Convert.ToInt32("abc")` but can not handle `("abc").toInt();`

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't know, there is the static class Convert for that (it contains methods like .ToFloat and .ToInt)